# Cannot fathom out why Javascript regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate some input to check that it is a positive currency value of the format:

`0.5`, `0.55`, `5` (note this one), `5.5`, `5.55`, `55` etc etc.

The code that I'm using is:

```
  if ($("#gross").val()>0 && !/^\d+?\.?\d?\d$/.test($("#gross").val())) {
    alert($("#gross").val() + " is invalid currency");
  }
```

It works for everything except a single digit, eg `5` (and `5.`) but does work for `5.5`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I fathom that it's a mistake in the regular expression used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've forgotten to add a `?` at the end, before the `$`. A better way of doing it would be the following:

```
/^\d+?\.?\d{0,2}$/
```

This checks that there are up to two decimal places for the number - if you'd like to check for any amount, you could use something like:

```
/^(?!\.$)(?:(?!0\d)(\d*)\.?(\d[0-9]*))$/
```

Note that it's a good idea to explicitly convert your string into a number, and also cache the value of `#gross`.

```
var grossVal = $("#gross").val();
if (+grossVal > 0 && !/^\d+?\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(grossVal)) {
    alert(grossVal + " is invalid currency");
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript, `\d` and `[0-9]` are the same.  In some flavors `\d` is equivalent to `\p{Nd}` (Unicode decimal digit), but I don't know of any flavor where it matches letters.  Are you perhaps thinking of `\w`?

Comment: @AlanMoore: indeed, don't know what I was thinking. _The production CharacterClassEscape :: d evaluates by returning the ten-element set of characters containing the characters 0 through 9 inclusive._

Answer (score 2):

`+?` will match the fewest possible matches, in this case, 1 digit.

I think you're looking for something like:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Which would be a series of digits, potentially followed by a decimal and anywhere between 0 to 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using alternation to break down a regular expression into the form `a|b|c|d`.

Then we can use several different forms, let:

```
a = 0                       -- 0
b = [1-9]\d*                -- n (non-zero integer), n cannot start with 0
c = 0[.]\d{1,2}             -- 0.x or 0.xy
d = [1-9]\d*[.]\d{1,2}      -- n.x or n.xy, n (non-zero integer)
```

This will allow us to reject values like `09` and `1.`, as they are not covered by any of the individual forms accepted.

Comment: Note that the questioner explicitly said that `5.` should be accepted by the regular expression ("_eg 5 (and 5.)_").

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Oh, yeah .. that's buried further down - I just went off of the initial listing. (This doesn't accept that as written, but can be trivially adapted as so.)

Comment: Anyway, +1 for suggesting people don't just cram their whole regex into one way.